# javascript check if value is a mongo.cursor

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to check if the value returned from a javascript function is a mongo cursor (in meteor js) or something else, since the function can return an array, a mongo.cursor or something else *(considered unacceptable)*

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I never used _meteor_  but can't you just test if it is an Array, if the function you expect is available for the object or otherwise handle it as unknown object?

Comment: Can you give a sample of your code? Because, when you call `var cur = db.collection.find()` is by default if `DBCursor`. If you call `var arrayCursor = db.collection.find().toArray()` it is `Array`. There is a weird way to know if it is Array or DBCursor: `arrayCursor.hasOwnProperty("length")` returns `true` while for DBCursor.length()

Comment: not sure to understand your suggestion: I can surely test if result is an array; but if it isn't, I still need to check if it is a mongo.cursor or something else

Comment: if you call `find()` be sure that is DBCursor

Comment: Read more here: [http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator to do this:

```
if (mysteryObject instanceof Mongo.Cursor) {
    // Yep, it's a Cursor.
}
```